# Firebase frameworks embedded in private iOS framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, frameworks

I want to create private framework in my XCode workspace with embedded Firebase frameworks for use in two apps in this workspace.

My workspace structure is:

MyApps.xcworkspace

---- FirebaseKit.xcodeproj

---- ---- FirebaseKit

---- ---- ---- Manager.swift

---- ---- Products

---- ---- ---- FirebaseKit.framework

---- ---- Frameworks

---- ---- ---- FirebaseAnalytics.framework

---- ---- ---- FirebaseDatabase.framework

---- ---- ---- FirebaseStorage.framework

---- MyApp1.xcodeproj

---- ---- MyApp1

---- ---- ---- AppDelegate.swift

---- ---- Frameworks

---- ---- ---- FirebaseKit.framework

---- MyApp2.xcodeproj

---- ---- MyApp2

---- ---- ---- AppDelegate.swift

---- ---- Frameworks

---- ---- ---- FirebaseKit.framework

My FirebaseKit.Manager.swift file is:

```
import Firebase

public struct Manager {
    public static func configure() {
        FIRApp.configure()
    }
}
```

Then I build FirebaseKit - Succeded

MyApp1.AppDelegate.swift (and MyApp2.AppDelegate.swift) code is:

```
import FirebaseKit     //<-- error is here "Missing required module 'Firebase'"

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseKit.Manager.configure()
        return true
    }
}
```

When I try to build MyApp1 or MyApp2, I get the error "Missing required module 'Firebase'"

I tried both ways:

- use Cocoapods in FirebaseKit
- without Cocoapods (added Firebase frameworks manually)

Is it possible to embed framework in other framework to use in the same (or different) xcworkspace? 
I tried to find docs or other answers, but no luck.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you fix it?